# List user comments in author page

Tags: comments, author, author-template, wp-comment-query

I'm trying to display a list of the author comments in the authors page but it only shows *No comments made*.

How can I list user comments in the authors page?

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'user_id' => $user->ID,
    'number' => 10, // how many comments to retrieve
    'status' => 'approve'
    );

$comments = get_comments( $args );

if ( $comments )
{
    $output.= "<ul>\n";
    foreach ( $comments as $c )
    {
    $output.= '<li>';
    $output.= '<a href="'.get_comment_link( $c->comment_ID ).'">';
    $output.= get_the_title($c->comment_post_ID);
    $output.= '</a>, Posted on: '. mysql2date('m/d/Y', $c->comment_date, $translate);
    $output.= "</li>\n";
    }
    $output.= '</ul>';

    echo $output;
} else { echo "No comments made";} ?>
```

Comment: Is `$user->ID` set ? What happens if you remove the `'user_id'` part? I assume you got plenty of approved comments.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [WP_Comment_Query](https://generatewp.com/wp_comment_query/) and make sure you have the right [Author ID](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Using_Author_Information) from the [Author Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Setting_Up_for_Author_Information).

```
// WP_Comment_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'user_id'        => $user->ID,
    'post_status'    => 'approve',
    'number'         => '10',
);

// The Comment Query
$comments = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments->query( $args );

// The Comment Loop
if ( $comments ) {

    $output.= "<ul>\n";

    foreach ( $comments as $c ) {
        $output.= '<li>';
        $output.= '<a href="'.get_comment_link( $c->comment_ID ).'">';
        $output.= get_the_title($c->comment_post_ID);
        $output.= '</a>, Posted on: '. mysql2date('m/d/Y', $c->comment_date, $translate);
        $output.= "</li>\n";
    }

    $output.= '</ul>';

    echo $output;
} else {
    echo 'No comments found.';
}
```